# Getting Java- and Javascript-generated charts to look similar

Tags: java, javascript, charts, jfreechart

I'm having the following scenario: I'm displaying charts in the client side using the Javascript chart library Raphael. On clicking download I need to generate the same chart into pdf and display it to the user. I'm using JFreeChart to create charts on the server side. The problem is that since I'm using two different chart libraries, both look different. What is the solution for this?

The chart should be free for commercial use.

Comment: You could try Google Chart API

Comment: use raphael on server side to match?

Comment: but jFreechart is better looking one , i want somethng like tht in client side too .

Answer (score 2):

4 options here :

1. Use Google Chart. http://code.google.com/apis/chart/
2. JQuery Chart. http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/top-jquery-chart-libraries-interactive-charts/
3. Create Applet, use your JFreeChart and put it on the applet. Then provide the data from javascript to the applet. (If you really insist to make a very similar UI)
4. On the servlet convert your chart to image, and store it in session. Later on, in your JSP, get the image from the session. check this [link](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=9621) for the details. But this one won't exactly the same as option no 3.